# Multiple identical keys from Python dict to JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to create JSON object in Python, and it works just fine despite the fact that I can't get multiple keys with the same name - but I need to do it.
Here's a function:

```
     findings = AutoTree()
                findings['report']['numberOfConditions'] = num_cond            
                if r == 'Mammography':
                    f_temp = df['Relevant findings'].values.tolist()[0:8]
                    f_list = [x for i, x in enumerate(f_temp) if i == f_temp.index(x)]
                    f_num_total = len(f_list)
                    f_rand = random.randrange(1, f_num_total + 1)
                    iter_params_mass = ['shape', 'margin', 'density']
                    for i in range(num_cond):
                        br = get_birad(row, 2, 7)
                        cond = camelCase(get_cond_name())
                        findings[cond]['biRad'] = br
                        for k in range(f_rand + 1):
                            f = camelCase(random.choice(f_list))
                            #f = 'mass'
                            if f == 'mass':
                                rep_temp = create_rep(iter_params_mass, row, f, r)
                                findings[cond][f] = rep_temp 
   """I also have a lot elif conditions, and it just grabs parameters."""
                     report = json.dumps(findings)
                 print(report)
```

Output:

```
{  
   "report":{  
      "id":85,
      "name":"Lydia",
      "age":39,
      "relevantModality":"Mammography",
      "numberOfConditions":2
   },
   "ductEctasia":{  
      "biRad":"birad[1]",
      "calcifications":[  
         {  
            "typicallyBenign":"Vascular",
            "suspiciousMorphology":"Coarse heterogeneous",
            "distribution":"Diffuse"
         }
      ],
      "lymphNodes":[  
         {  
            "lymphNodes":"Lymph nodes \u2013 axillary"
         }
      ]   
   }
}
```

And I want to have multiple "lymphNodes" and "calcifications" objects. Is it possible? Maybe, you can suggest another way to create JSON object, not nested dictionaries? The problem is that I need to create object respectively to random parameter chosen from the database.

Comment: You already use lists for "lymphNodes" and "calcifications" so what stops you from having multiple objects in it? Also, method you use (list) is proper way to have multiple elements of same key in JSON.

Comment: It just doesn't iterate through it and doesn't append.

Comment: Maybe you can share full code and try to be more clear about your problem because I'm not sure what you're referring to or what the problem is.